# ios/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap' not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, boringssl

The problem arises when attempting to use @react-native-firebase/firestore. While Android appears to function flawlessly, iOS is presenting the issue described below:

I've been struggling with this issue for over a week now. After successfully running "pod install," I attempted to launch my iOS app from Xcode. However, I'm encountering the following problem:

Error:

#### ios/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap' not found

/Users/mac/Documents/Gitlab/hybrid-app/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/trace/v3/zipkin.upb.c module map file '/Users/mac/Documents/Gitlab/hybrid-app/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap' not found

I'm seeking help to overcome this situation as it's been quite challenging to resolve.

yarn add @react-native-firebase/firestore
cd ios
pod install
run on ios using xcode so i'm facing still this kind of issue.

**your Error text**
The module map file '/Users/mac/Documents/Gitlab/hybrid-app/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/trace/v3/zipkin.upb.c' is pointing to a missing file at '/Users/mac/Documents/Gitlab/hybrid-app/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/openssl_grpc/BoringSSL-GRPC.modulemap'.

I've been dealing with an issue for over a week now, and I'm hoping to find a solution. After successfully running "pod install" for my project, I'm encountering a problem when I try to run my iOS app from Xcode. The error message I'm getting is:

i'm trying multiple solution but no success so i'm asking to expert what the solution of this kid of error,

The CocoaPods 1.9.0, the capability to specify dynamic/static linkage for each pod in the Podfile should get it better. It introduced the use of use_frameworks! :linkage => :static which is an even better approach than use_modular_headers! same issue